# Copy-Paste error in LaTeX

Tags: errors, mactex, copy-paste

When I try to copy some text from a Word page or pdf an paste it to LaTeX, I get the error below. Any idea how to fix this?

PS: I am using LaTeX on a Mac

While the text which I typed my self works perfectly

```
Birbirleriyle ilişkili $p$ tane değişkeni bir araya getirerek, az sayıda ve ilişkisiz ve kavramsal olarak anlamlı yeni değişkenler (faktörler, boyutlar) bulmayı amaçlayan amaçlayan çok değişkenli istatistiksel bir yöntemdir.
```

The text below I copied & pasted from a pdf file yields the error below.

```
 Tanımlanan her faktör, değişkenler arasındaki ilişkinin ölçülmesi sonucu aynı özelliği ölçen birbiri ile ilişkili değişken setinden oluşur.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a copy/paste of the offending line, please?

Comment: @egreg, I have edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, but if I copy from the question I have no problem. Can you make a small example available somewhere?

Comment: @egreg, I produced an example and no problem at all. I suppose this has something to do with the rest of my code

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX has problem with some of the characters with accents you used. This problem can be solved using various techniques:

1. Add this into your preamble (and change your source file encoding to UTF-8):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Or \usepackage{fontspec} for XeLaTeX
\usepackage[english]{babel}   % Babel, replace with your language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % Font encoding
\usepackage{lmodern,cmap}     % lmodern font, correctly copyable characters in pdf
```

2. Use XeLaTeX which uses UTF-8 encoding and has no problem with any UTF-8 characters. In order to use it just change your `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Don't forget that your source tex file has to be in UTF-8, otherwise XeLaTeX will complain.
3. Use LaTeX's accents instead of these characters, e.g. instead of `ğ` use `\u{g}`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this happens when copying and pasting from PDFs, and it has more to do with your reader than your LaTeX IDE.

I bet if you copy+paste from your PDF to your notepad you'll get some weird characters for your `utf8` ones (try to do this to see what happens).

The fact that you just mentioned there is no problem with the `utf8` characters you directly type is what makes me believe there is a problem with your copying process ---Not that you are doing something wrong, is just the way these funny characters are interpreted.